# Maven version in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded latest Eclipse for Java.

```
Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212
```

How to know which version of Maven is used in Eclipse as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the version of Maven used in the preferences (Windows -> Preferences Maven -> Installations)

[image: Maven Preferences]

This is from an older installation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be visible under Preferences -> Maven.

Probably something like 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window -> Preference -> Maven -> Installations`

You should be able to see the default maven version.